# Why it's not a good idea to set different population sizing for test and holdout?

Tags: statistics

So we are trying to run an A/B testing with changes applying to 10% of the population. My PM told me we should set a separate control team at 10% too so we can compare the 10% test and 10% control later. My question is why is it a better idea to compare the 10% test vs and 10% control instead of 10% test vs the 90% rest population, which is essentially everyone who don't see the changes?

Comment: May be a more appropriate question for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question and approach is unclear, be more clear about what exactly are you doing and why.